VS Code not finding any installed packages in terminal on mac installation
I have a new mac setup on apple silicon (M2). I've installed homebrew, nvm, and pnpm via the mac terminal (zsh) and added all to path, and have verified the installations by typing nvm -v command etc.
However, the terminal in VS Code gives me command not found error for all:

When I type echo $PATH the path variables are the same in both terminals. What can I do to allow vs code to find these installed packages?

1. Ensure VS Code Is Using Your Default Shell

Open VS Code.
Go to Settings (Cmd + , or File > Preferences > Settings).
Search for terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx (or terminal.integrated.shell.osx for older versions of VS Code).
Ensure the default profile is set to zsh:


{
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh" }

If the setting does not exist, add the following to your settings.json file:

{
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh" }

Restart the VS Code terminal to apply the changes.
2. Ensure Environment Variables Are Loaded
For macOS, environment variables defined in your shell configuration files (like .zshrc) may not be loaded in VS Code's integrated terminal. To fix this:

Open your ~/.zshrc file:

nano ~/.zshrc


Ensure you have the necessary exports for nvm, pnpm, and Homebrew:

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" # Homebrew
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" # nvm
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion" ] && . "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion"
export PATH="$HOME/.pnpm:$PATH" # pnpm


Reload your shell configuration:

source ~/.zshrc


Restart VS Code to load the updated environment.

3. Load the Shell Environment for GUI Applications
macOS doesn’t always load the same shell configuration for GUI applications like VS Code. To fix this:

Create or edit the ~/.zprofile file:
nano ~/.zprofile

Add the following to load your .zshrc for GUI apps:
if [ -f ~/.zshrc ]; then
source ~/.zshrc
fi

Save the file and restart VS Code.


4. Check the VS Code Terminal Profile
adf

Open the VS Code integrated terminal.

Type:
echo $SHELL


Ensure it outputs /bin/zsh or the path to your zsh shell.

If it doesn’t, you may need to manually set the terminal profile. Go
to the Command Palette (Cmd + Shift + P) and select Terminal: Select
Default Profile. Choose zsh from the list.


Verify the Fix


Open a new terminal in VS Code.

Run:
nvm -v
pnpm -v
brew -v


These commands should now work without the command not found error.
If the problem persists, ensure your VS Code is fully updated, and check for any conflicting extensions or settings that might override terminal behavior. Let me know if you need further assistance!
Good Luck :)

Thank you, I will try this all when I'm back at my workstation!
